# is `cgroup-tools` using cgroup v1 or v2

Tags: cgroup

I have ubuntu 21.10 installed. I confirmed that I am using cgroup v2 by running `mount`, which shows `cgrup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2`.

When I want to use `cgcreate` from `cgroup-tools` to create a new group for `cpu`:

```sh
sudo cgcreate -g cpu:newgroup  # or
sudo cgcreate -g all:newgroup
```

it fails with error:

```sh
cgcreate: libcgroup initialization failed: Cgroup is not mounted
```

I have several questions:

- Is this because `cgroup-tools` is for cgroup v1?
- What should I use to create new cgroups for cgroup v2?
- How to create persistent cgroups (when booting) using config files for cgroup v2?

Comment: A bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcgroup/+bug/1948415

Comment: It seems that it is possible to revert to v1 with a kernel param, maybe that will serve as a workaround for anyone stuck on 21.10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646317/sys-fs-cgroup-memory-memory-limit-in-bytes-not-present-in-fedora-33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current `cgroup-tools` (in Ubuntu 21.10 and earlier) is 0.41 which only works with CGroups v1 and is no longer supported. Jammy (22.04) will have the new [`cgroup-tools` version 2.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/cgroup-tools) that [supports CGroups v2](https://github.com/libcgroup/libcgroup/releases/tag/v2.0).

Comment: can I download this `cgroup-tools version 2.0` and use it in ubuntu 21.10?

Comment: Theoretically, you should be able to - just download the required deb files and use `dpkg -i` to install them. You'd need to also download the `libcgroup1` package linked from the Ubuntu Packages page I linked to, as it is required. I do recommend checking first whether something you have installed requires the old `libcgroup1` by running `apt rdepends --installed libcgroup1`, but there should be nothing there, by default, except the tools package.

Comment: thanks. I will try it when I have time.

Comment: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 to try it out, but it unfortunately did not solve the issue. `dpkg` does say that I have cgroup-tools 2.0-2.

Comment: `cgcreate` on jammy works for me - the above command completes without an error. Check that the file system is still mounted.

Comment: I take that back. I think I had tried running it without `sudo`. It does work.

Comment: BTW, I haven't managed to run `cgexec` without sudo if you have any clues about that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406329/how-to-run-cgexec-without-sudo-as-current-user-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-cgroups-v2 :-)