# How to run cgexec without sudo as current user on Ubuntu 22.04 with cgroups v2, failing with "cgroup change of group failed"?

Tags: 22.04, cgroup

I've tried the procedures from:

- [Cgroups error: cgroup change of group failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651741/cgroups-error-cgroup-change-of-group-failed)
- [How to use cgroup in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345055/how-to-use-cgroup-in-ubuntu-13-04)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197718/does-managing-cgroups-require-root-access

but they don't work on Ubuntu 22.04, presumably because of the update to cgroups v2:

```
sudo cgcreate -a $USER:$USER -g memory:myGroup -t $USER:$USER
sudo cgset -r memory.max=500M myGroup
sudo cgset -r memory.swap.max=0 myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup id
```

fails with:

```
cgroup change of group failed
```

It works if I run with `sudo`

```
sudo cgexec -g memory:myGroup id
```

but then the command runs as `root`, and I want it to run as the current user instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the [Linux Kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#namespace) and find the following (emphasis mine):

> cgroup.procs
>
> > A read-write new-line separated values file which exists on all cgroups.
> > ...
> > A PID can be written to migrate the process associated with the PID to the cgroup. The writer should match all of the following conditions.
> >
> > - It must have write access to the “cgroup.procs” file.
> > - **It must have write access to the “cgroup.procs” file of the common ancestor of the source and destination cgroups.**
> >
> > ...

In this scenario, the common ancestor is `/`. So I make `cgroup.procs` of the root group writable:

```
sudo chmod o+w /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs
```

And now I can use `cgexec` as any non-root user. Not knowing if there is any security implication though.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve it you need to boot your host system into CGroupV1 mode by modifying your kernel’s boot arguments to include:
`systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false"

sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, I'd really like to find a v2 solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I used to run a few resource-intensive tools with `cgexec` in cgroups v1. I'm not so sure this is supported in cgroups v2; at least I couldn't get it to work.

After too much time spent looking into it this is how I managed to get things going for me in Ubuntu 22.04 + cgroups v2.

### 1. Create a cgroup `europe` and (in my case) tweak permissions

```
$ cd /sys/fs/cgroup/
$ sudo mkdir europe create

$ ls -ld europe
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 0 out 28 22:50 europe
$ sudo chmod a+rx europe
$ ls -ld europe
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 out 28 22:50 europe
```

Without changing permissions two things happen to me: can't cat stuff inside group without sudo, and `systemd-cgtop --depth 1` returns `Failed to refresh: Permission denied`.

### 2. Limit CPU to 3 cores and RAM to 16G

I had multiple controllers available (`cgroup.controllers`), but the only ones being passed down the subtree were `memory` and `pids` so I added the missing `cpu` controller.

```
$ cat cgroup.controllers                       // all available
cpuset cpu io memory hugetlb pids rdma misc
$ cat cgroup.subtree_control                   // for subgroups
memory pids
$ sudo bash -c 'echo '+cpu' > cgroup.subtree_control'
$ cat cgroup.subtree_control                   // now includes CPU
cpu memory pids

$ cat europe/cgroup.controllers                // can confirm in subgrp
cpu memory pids
```

Now limit CPU and RAM:

```
$ cat europe/memory.max
max
$ cat europe/cpu.max
max 100000

$ echo '16G' | sudo tee europe/memory.max
16G
$ echo '300000 100000' | sudo tee europe/cpu.max
300000 100000

$ cat europe/memory.max
17179869184
$ cat europe/cpu.max
300000 100000
```

### 3. Run some stuff

We can add PIDs to to `europe/cgroup.procs` that will then be executing in group `europe`.

Instead of starting a process and then adding its PID what I do is add the PID of a terminal window. Then everything run in that shell will be executed in the group.

Open another terminal:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/europe/cgroup.procs

$ echo $$ | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/europe/cgroup.procs
25982

$ cat europe/cgroup.procs
25982
26104
$ cat europe/cgroup.procs
25982
26105
$ cat europe/cgroup.procs
25982
26106
```

The first PID is the one referring to the terminal (matches `echo $$` in bash) and the second PID is the command `cat` that's why everytime I ran the command the second PID was different.

### 4. Remove group when not needed

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/europe/cgroup.procs
$ sudo rmdir /sys/fs/cgroup/europe
```

If there are still processes in `europe/cgroup.procs` we get an error. In this example close the terminal that was added to the group in the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `cgexec` with `su` like this:

```
sudo cgexec -g memory:myGroup -- su -c 'exec id' $USER
```

or simply with `-s`:

```
sudo cgexec -g memory:myGroup -- su -s /usr/bin/id $USER
```

But the latter will rewrite `$SHELL` variable as the program itself.